# How to read file from my repo with Fastlane?

Tags: android, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, fastlane

I am using Fastlane to auto deploy my apk to hockeyApp. I am trying to upload the release notes with it, but I cant seem to read the file that is in the repo but fastlane cannot seem to find it. This is the crash report from the CI server. Thanks in advance.

```
 Error in your Fastfile at line 86
    [09:34:20]:     84:               hockey(api_token: release_token,
    [09:34:20]:     85:                      apk: apk_path,
    [09:34:20]:  => 86:                      notes: File.read(“./auto_deployment/release_notes.txt”))
    [09:34:20]:     87:     end
    [09:34:20]:     88: 
    [09:34:20]: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./auto_deployment/release_notes.txt
```

Comment: have you check that the file relative path is correct?

Comment: The file exists in `projectRoot/auto_deployment/release_notes.txt` .
In a terminal thats how i used to access it `./auto_deployment/release_notes.txt`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are in `projectRoot/fastlane` when you execute `fastlane`, so you need to write `../auto_deployment/release_notes.txt` to access the file you want.